# Parent id not insert to child table whit OneToMany relationship in java hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have entity `ServiceConfig` with to OneToMany relationship:

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "serviceConfig", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<NotificationItem> notificationItems;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "serviceConfig", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<QosItem> qosItems;
```

And in each child class, I have:

```
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "TD_SERVICE_CONFIG_ID")
    private ServiceConfig serviceConfig;
```

When I fetch new `ServiceConfig` - I have 3 tables, `ServiceConfig` , `NotificationItem` and `QosItem`. In `NotificationItem` and `QosItem` tables, I have empty column `TD_SERVICE_CONFIG_ID` but all data inserted.

How can I config hibernate(annotations or another configs) for successful insert parent id to `TD_SERVICE_CONFIG_ID` column of child?

Comment: How do you save the entity?! Do you set the ServiceConfig for the two NotificationItem and QosItem?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your configuration looks fine.

I suspect (although obviously can't tell for sure without seeing your code) that you are not setting the inverse side of the relationship, which is required.
You would add a `NotificationItem` as follows:

```
NotificationItem item = new NotificationItem();
item.setServiceConfig(service);  //set the other side of the bi-directional relationship
servive.getNotificationItems().add(item);
```

The middle line is the important one here.

Comment: Hi I have tried in the above mentioned way, but in database two entries are inserted instead one.